# Why Switch statement only working with true keyword?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Can anyone explain to me why first one is not working and second one is working?

*First Statement*

```
function test(n) {
    switch (n) {
    case (n == 0 || n == 1):
        console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
        break;
    case (n >= 2):
        console.log("Number is greater than 1")
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Default");
    }
}
```

*Second Statement*

```
function test(n) {
    switch (true) {
    case (n == 0 || n == 1):
        console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
        break;
    case (n >= 2):
        console.log("Number is greater than 1")
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Default");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `n` is not equal to the cases `n == 0 || n == 1` or `n >= 2`? That said, you should *really* be using `if`/`else` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter which is given to the switch will be compared using `===`. In cases which you have, you have expressions which result to `boolean` type: `n==0 || n==1` or `n >= 2`. When you pass a number , it tries to compare your number with a result given from the expression in cases. So for example with the given number `1` it tries to compare `1 === (1 == 0 || 1 == 1)` -> `1 === true` which returns false (strict comparison). So you get the `Default` text every time.

For the first case, you need to have numbers in the `cases` of your switch , not a `boolean` (`n==0 || n==1` results to `boolean`).

With the second case, you have in the switch value `true` of type `boolean`.When you pass again `1` the comparing goes like `true === (1 == 0 || 1 == 1)` -> `true === true` and it returns true. So you get the desired result according to your value `n`. But the second case has no goals with using `true` as the value. You can replace it with a `if else if` statement.

If you want to get the same result for many cases you need to write 2 cases above each other. See this

```
case 0:
case 1:
  result
```

Here the cases have type `number`, not `boolean`.

**Code example.**

```js
function test(n){
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
    break;
    case 2:
    console.log("Number is 2")
    break;
    default:
    console.log("Default");}
}

test(0);
test(1);
test(2)
```

Comment: What if I give 3 into function parameter? As there is no expression handling 3 or greater than 3, So it'll go to default right?

Comment: With this example it will go to the `Default`. I wrote it only to show the case of `0` and `1`. If you have many cases you can do like your second example, but with two cases it will be better to use `if else if` statement

Comment: I've worked in VB and we could simply write such expressions case (n == 0 || n == 1) or even give a range like case 1 to 20:

Comment: can we do something similar in JavaScript?

Comment: There is no range in Javascript. As how you will do it in the `VB` using `if-else`, same you can do here

Comment: Not with if-else I was saying that we ca do this with switch statement cases in VB.

Comment: Here there is no range concept in the case.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is shorthand for a bunch of `if`s.

```
switch(n) {
    case x:
        a();
        break;
    case y:
        b();    
        break;
}
```

... is equivalent to:

```
if(n == x) {
     a();
} else if(n == y) {
     b();
}
```

So your first piece of code:

```
switch (n) {
   case (n==0 || n==1):
      console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
      break;
case (n>=2):
     console.log("Number is greater than 1")
     break;
default:
    console.log("Default");}
}
```

... is equivalent to:

```
if(n == (n==0 || n==1)) {
   console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
} else if ( n == ( n >= 2)) {
   console.log("Number is greater than 1");
} else {
   console.log("Default");
}
```

I hope you can see that `n == (n==0 || n==1)` and `n == ( n >= 2)` are both nonsense. If `n` is 0, for example, the first will evaluate to `0 == true`. In many languages this will cause a compiler error (comparing different types). I don't especially want to think about what it does in Javascript!

Your second example:

```
switch (true) {
case (n==0 || n==1):
   console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
   break;
case (n>=2):
   console.log("Number is greater than 1")
   break;
default:
   console.log("Default");
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(true == (n==0 || n==1)) {
    console.log("Number is either 0 or 1");
} else if(true == (n>=2)) {
    console.log("Number is greater than 1");
} else {
    console.log("Default");
}
```

... in which at least the condition statements `true == (n==0 || n==1)` and `true == (n >=2)` make sense.

But this is an unconventional way to use `switch` in most languages. The normal form is to use the value you're testing as the parameter to `switch` and for each `case` to be a possible value for it:

```
switch(n) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
         console.log("n is 0 or 1");
         break;
    case 2:
         console.log("n is 2);
         break;
    default:
         console.log("n is some other value");
}
```

However `switch` doesn't provide a cleverer `case` than a full equality check. So there's no `case >2 && <5`.

Your can either use your trick using `switch(true)` (in Javascript -- there are many languages in which this won't work), or use `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) uses strict comparison.

You take a number in the switch statement and in cases, just comparsions which return a boolean value.

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first `case` clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), `===`) and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements. (If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.) If no matching `case` clause is found, the program looks for the optional `default` clause, and if found, transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements. If no `default` clause is found, the program continues execution at the statement following the end of `switch`. By convention, the `default` clause is the last clause, but it does not need to be so.